# ordenar json sacado de una base de datos verticalmente PHP

Tags: php, json

Estoy convirtiendo una tabla de MySQL en un arreglo de Json, pero al generarlo me salen todos los valores en una sola lineal, necesito ordenarlos verticalmente aquí mi código, muchas gracias.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Usuarios";
mysqli_set_charset($conexion,"utf8");
if(!$result = mysqli_query($conexion,$query)) die();
$datos = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

{
    $id = $row["id"];          
    $nombre = $row["nombre"];                  
    $razon = $row["razonSocial"];        
    $correo = $row["correoElectronico"];          
    $numero = $row["numeroContacto"];       
    $terminos = $row["terminos"];
$datos[] = array('id'=> $id,'nombre'=>$nombre,'razon social'=>$razon,'correo'=>$correo,'numero'=>$numero,'terminos'=>$terminos);
$json_datos = json_encode($datos);
}
echo$json_datos;
```

este es el resultado.
[{"id":"1","nombre":"Carlos Ceballos","razon social":"natural","correo":"0","numero":"2147483647","terminos":"acepta"},{"id":"2","nombre":"yiseli Duran","razon social":"mi casaya","correo":"0","numero":"369852147","terminos":"acepta"},{"id":"3","nombre":"anderson Duran","razon social":"mi casaya","correo":"yiseli@messenger.com","numero":"369852147","terminos":"acepta"},{"id":"4","nombre":"mateo gutierrez","razon social":"Micasaya","correo":"yiseli@michat.com","numero":"2147483647","terminos":"acepta"},{"id":"5","nombre":"carlos perez","razon social":"ddd","correo":"aaa@hotmail.com","numero":"2147483647","terminos":"acepta"}]

Comment: Prueba con `$json_datos = json_encode($datos, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`

Comment: me genera el mismo resultado, 1 sola linea.

Comment: ¿Lo estas viendo en html? Prueba `echo '<pre>'.$json_datos.'</pre>';`

Comment: así si me funciono, muchísimas gracias.